# How to Alter Table in the mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having a problem while `ALTER TABLE`. The reason am altering table is  "Because of its length, this column might not be editable."

[image]

MySQL said: Documentation

> **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMN description (MAX_ROWS = 1000000000 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=1000000000)' at line 1**

My Sql Query

```
ALTER TABLE oc_information_description COLUMN description (MAX_ROWS = 1000000000 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=1000000000)
```

Should be the table length increase and don't truncate my data.

Comment: Is the engine for this table myisam or innodb? (you can check using show create table oc_information_description)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root problem is the following note on phpMyAdmin on column `description`:

> Because of its length, this column might not be editable.

In this case the current data type `TEXT` is to small so there is no space to add more data to the field. You can change the data type with the following `ALTER TABLE` to a bigger one (`MEDIUMTEXT` or `LONGTEXT`):

```
ALTER TABLE oc_information_description MODIFY description MEDIUMTEXT
```

---

Your second issue is the wrong sql syntax (trying to solve the first issue):

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMN description (MAX_ROWS = 1000000000 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=1000000000)' at line 1

You can't specify the `AVG_ROW_LENGTH` or `MAX_ROWS` for a specific column. You can specify them for table only. You can change these values with the following [`ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html):

```
ALTER TABLE oc_information_description AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 1000000000, MAX_ROWS = 1000000000
```

> `table_options` signifies table options of the kind that can be used in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, such as `ENGINE`, `AUTO_INCREMENT`, `AVG_ROW_LENGTH`, `MAX_ROWS`, `ROW_FORMAT`, or `TABLESPACE`.

Comment: then how to add the table length, because the problem is this "description" is truncated my data please see here http://prntscr.com/m8a67e